# Mostrar dados vindos de um JSON em uma listview

Tags: c#, json, ios, xamarin

```
namespace Monitorizacao.UI.Pages
{

    public class Post {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TestAPIPage : ContentPage
    {
        private const string url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        private HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        private ObservableCollection<Post> _posts;

        public TestAPIPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(url);
            var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(content);

            _posts = new ObservableCollection<Post>(posts);
            List.ItemsSource = _posts;
            Console.Write(posts);
            base.OnAppearing();
        }


    }
}
```

Eu tenho um JSON e quando eu tento mostrá-lo numa `listview` depois de deserializar, os dados não mostram o que eu quero.

Quando faço *debug* do app, todos os dados são recebidos.

Comment: Henrique, faça um teste e mude a linha **`List.ItemsSource = _posts;`** para **`List.ItemsSource = _posts.Select(p => p.Title).ToList();`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que acontece é que a *listview* vai chamar o método `ToString` de cada objeto para mostrá-lo.

Você tem duas alternativas viáveis aqui:

#### 1. Passar uma lista de `strings` para a `listview`

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    var content = await _client.GetStringAsync(url);
    var posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Post>>(content);

    _posts = new ObservableCollection<Post>(posts);
    List.ItemsSource = _posts.Select(x => x.Title).ToList();
    // (^) onde tem x.Title, você muda para a propriedade que queres mostrar        

    Console.Write(posts);
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

#### 2. Escrever um método `ToString` em `Post` para mostrar o que você quiser na `listview`

```
public class Post 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id} - Título: {Title}";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Cara, MUITO obrigado, estava tentando arrumar isso faz umas 5 horas

Comment: cara vc tem skype?

Comment: @HenriqueRodrigues Tenho, por quê? (Mal a demora, estava de férias)